# How to calculate the number of bases of a Totally Unimodular matrix(TUM)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, total-unimodularity, unimodular-matrices

I have been reading about TUM and my question is why the number of nonsingular $r \times  r$ submatrices of the TU matrix $A$ of rank $r$ will give me the number of bases of $A$?

Recall that the definition of a TUM is as follows:

*A rank r totally unimodular matrix is a matrix over $\mathbb R$ for which every submatrix has determinant in $\{ 0, 1, -1 \}.$*

Could anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: What's a base of a matrix?

Comment: @joriki I meant basis sorry about that … it is the maximal linearly independent set in the matrix

Comment: Well, you correctly wrote "bases", which is the plural of both "base" and "basis", so the error is on my part in assuming that you meant "base". Now my question is: What's a basis of a matrix? I see you just edited your comment to answer that question, but I don't understand the answer. Do you mean the maximal linearly independent set of rows? Or of columns? Or of what?

Comment: Any of them, it does not matter, it is the rank of the matrix @joriki

Comment: What does "it" refer to in "it is the rank of the matrix"? A basis is not a rank. I'm aware that the row rank and column rank are equal, but you refer to "the number of bases", not the dimension of the bases. There could be different numbers of maximal linearly independent sets of rows and of columns. E.g. for $\pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&1&0\\1&2&1}$ there are three maximal independent sets of columns, but there's only one maximal independent set of rows.

Comment: @joriki I mean the dimension of the basis comes from the rank of the matrix ….. I think it in my sentence referred to the dimension of the basis. And yes you are correct I am asking about the number of bases not the dimension of a basis …. But I was just answering your question.

Comment: Well, you haven't answered it yet :-) If we agree that the number of bases (i.e. maximal independent sets) of the columns and the number of bases of the rows can differ, then you'd need to specify which of the two you mean.

Comment: I think I meant the number of bases of the rows@joriki

Comment: @joriki My question is specifically about the statement I mentioned at the first paragraph of my question, I am guessing that it is correct for rows only ..... I could be wrong though.

Comment: The number of nonsingular submatrices stays the same if we transpose the matrix, so the statement must be correct or incorrect for both rows and columns simultaneously. Maybe the definition of "basis" needs to be refined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is not correct in this form, unless I am misunderstanding the question. Consider the rank 1 totally unimodular matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1&1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
It has exactly 4 nonsingular submatrices and we can find two subsets of rows (or columns) that are bases of the row (or column) space of this matrix.